# one Library for multiDatabases

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, database-design

Im developing a windows forms application using C# 4.0 and that application is going to target different database engines like SQL, MySQL and Oracle i was wondering if there is a library that can talk to all the three engines instead of implementing my own layers for every one.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an ORM tool; I like [NHibernate](http://nhforge.org) But there are many more: see [a list at wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_object-relational_mapping_software).

Answer (score 2):

The problem is if you want to do anything remotely advanced (date arithmatic, generate primary keys, get the id of the last inserted record, pivot a table , use RANGE construct etc.) then both databases use completely different syntax.

The best solution (in the java world at least is either Ibatis or Hibernate) I know there is a .NET version of Hibernate I am not sure about Ibatis.

These libraries insulate your program from the various SQL dialects and provide a common API independent of the underlying database.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the classes in [System.Data.Common](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.aspx) you can make your code database independent:

[Writing Provider Independent Code in ADO.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9f29wbk.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know C#, but I know it will have a library for [ODBC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Database_Connectivity).

It looks like MS has one [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310988).

It's old, but actually it does the job just fine.  Virtually every DB in existence provides an ODBC driver.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout [DbLinq](http://code.google.com/p/dblinq2007/).

> DbLinq is THE LINQ provider that allows to use common databases with
>   an API close to Linq to SQL. It currently supports (by order of
>   appearance): MySQL, Oracle, PostgreSQL, SQLite, Ingres, Firebird...
>   And still SQL Server.